# Problema para mostrar una imagen al cargarla desde una base de datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Intento hacer un *login* con usuarios y una vez dentro de la aplicación que se muestre su foto de perfil. El problema es que a la hora de cargar de la base de datos la imagen me devuelve *null*. Si cargo la imagen de forma directa desde la galería la imagen sí que se muestra pero si la intento cargar de la base de datos no se muestra nada.

Para ir a mi galería empleo el siguiente código:

```
public void elegirFotoGaleria() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/");
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona"), 1);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        Uri miPath = data.getData();
        iconoCabecera.setImageURI(miPath);
        int ancho = 200;
        int alto = 200;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho, alto);
        iconoCabecera.setLayoutParams(params);

        textoNick.setText(extras.getString("NICK"));

        textoCorreo.setText(extras.getString("CORREO"));

        headView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        // Este es el código importante :)
        //Sin esto la vista siempre va a tener una dimensión de 0,0 y el mipmap será null
        headView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        headView.layout(0, 0, headView.getMeasuredWidth(), headView.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(headView.getDrawingCache());
        //limpiamos el caché
        headView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bitmap + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        guardarImagen(bitmap);
        actualizarFotoUsuario();

        iconoCabecera.setImageBitmap(buscarImagen());

        iconoCabecera.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Si en el `activityResult` cargo la imagen sí que se muestra correctamente. Con la siguiente función guardo la imagen en la base de datos:

```
    public void guardarImagen(Bitmap bitmap){
        // tamaño del baos depende del tamaño de tus imagenes en promedio
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20480);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , baos);
        byte[] blob = baos.toByteArray();
        // aqui tenemos el byte[] con el imagen comprimido, ahora lo guardemos en SQLite
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_IMG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
        db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_IMAGENES, null, values);
        db.close();

    }
```

Y por último, y aquí es donde viene el problema, busco la imagen en la base de datos.

```
 public Bitmap buscarImagen(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();

        Imagen i = null;
        String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE idImagen = 2");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            i = new Imagen();
            i.setIdImagen(cursor.getInt(0));
            i.setImg(cursor.getBlob(1));
            //byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(1);
            //ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(1));
            //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bais + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

El `byteArrayInputStream` no sale nulo pero sin embargo al cargar el *mipmap* éste me sale nulo provocando que la imagen no se muestre.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
```

Aquí es donde intento mostrar la imagen:

```
Bitmap b = buscarImagen();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), b + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        iconoCabecera.setImageBitmap(b);
        int ancho = 200;
        int alto = 200;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho, alto);
        iconoCabecera.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedo hacer comentarios con mi nivel pero el objetivo de mi respuesta es q me digas si puedes comprobar q se guardaron los datos correctamente en la BD. en cualquier caso podrías comprobar con una herramienta externa q se guardó en efecto la imagen y no otro dato corrupto como [esta](https://es.rakko.tools/tools/71/)

Comment: Los datos se guardan en la base de datos ya que me aparecen en el appInspection.

Comment: pudiste comprobar con el link q es la misma imagen y q no esta corrupta?

Comment: Este era uno de mis problemas, ya que algunas imágenes que tenía en el móvil al paracer estaban corruptas.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a adjuntar todo el código que he empleado ya que he cambiado algunos aspectos.

```
public void elegirFotoGaleria() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona"), 1);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri miPath = data.getData();
    iconoCabecera.setImageURI(miPath);
    int ancho = 200;
    int alto = 200;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho, alto);
    iconoCabecera.setLayoutParams(params);

    iconoCabecera.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // Este es el código importante :)
    //Sin esto la vista siempre va a tener una dimensión de 0,0 y el mipmap será null
    iconoCabecera.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    iconoCabecera.layout(0, 0, iconoCabecera.getMeasuredWidth(), iconoCabecera.getMeasuredHeight());

    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(iconoCabecera.getDrawingCache());
    //limpiamos el caché
    iconoCabecera.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    guardarImagen(b);
    contarId();
    actualizarFotoUsuario();
}
```

Con esta función guardo la imagen en la base de datos en la tabla llamada imágenes.

```
public void guardarImagen(Bitmap bitmap){
    // tamaño del baos depende del tamaño de tus imagenes en promedio
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20480);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , baos);
    byte[] blob = baos.toByteArray();
    // aqui tenemos el byte[] con el imagen comprimido, ahora lo guardemos en SQLite
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

    prueba = blob;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_IMG, blob);
    db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_IMAGENES, null, values);
    db.close();

}
```

Con esta función busco la imagen dentro de la base de datos.

```
public Bitmap buscarImagen(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();

    Imagen i = null;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_IMAGENES +
            " WHERE " + Utilidades.CAMPO_ID_IMAGEN + " = " + idImagen , null);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
        i = new Imagen();
        i.setIdImagen(cursor.getInt(0));

        idImagen = i.getIdImagen();

        byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(1);
        prueba = blob;

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
    }

    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

Con la siguiente función asigno la foto correspondiente a su usuario.

```
public void actualizarFotoUsuario() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIOS +
            " SET " + Utilidades.CAMPO_ID_IMAGEN + " = " + contador +
            " WHERE " + Utilidades.CAMPO_ID + " = " + idUs);

    db.close();
}
```

Con esta función consigo el id del usuario para que con la función de arriba se asigne la imagen al usuario correcto.

```
public void seleccionarIdImagenUsuario() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
    Usuario u = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + Utilidades.CAMPO_ID_IMAGEN +
            " FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIOS +
            " WHERE " + Utilidades.CAMPO_ID + " = " + idUs, null);

    if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        u = new Usuario();
        u.setIdImagen(cursor.getInt(0));
        idImagen = u.getIdImagen();
    }

    cursor.close();

    db.close();

}
```

Arriba del todo:

```
Bitmap b;
```

En el onCreate:

```
seleccionarIdImagenUsuario();
    b = buscarImagen();
    if(b == null) {
        iconoCabecera.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_correr);
    }
    else {
        iconoCabecera.setImageBitmap(b);
        int ancho = 200;
        int alto = 200;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho, alto);
        iconoCabecera.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```